# Solve a regression equation algebraically in python

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels

I fit a regression model using python `statsmodels.formula.api` package and obtain the coefficients/results. Here's the model:

```
Price ~ Availability + Income + unemployment + labor_force + HH
```

The coefficients are:

```
coef    
Intercept   18.8172
Availability 0.0860 
Income  9.213e-05   
unemployment -1.562e-05 
labor_force 5.78e-06
```

I'd like to calculate the value of Availability for when `Price = 0` and for different values of independent variable which vary by time. Basically, solve for `Availability` when `Price = 0`.

`0 = Intercept + b1 * Avail + b2 * Income + b3 * U + b4 * L`

I need python to solve this equation for `Avail`.

I realize I can do this with a python function by simply solving the equation, ,however, I was wondering if there are any in built methods I could use to obtain the equation and solve?

Comment: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html